# How to do looping inside widget in flutter

Tags: loops, for-loop, flutter

I am trying to use `for` looping inside my widget... here is my simple code

```
Widget cek() {
  for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    return Center(child: Text("check"));
  }
}
```

but I always get one of `Text("check")` that show on my screen... is there a way to use `for` loop inside my widget?

Comment: if you want to return multiple widgets and then you need to return a list of widgets ... here you are returning a single widget (the first time loop runs to be exact)

Comment: You are getting only one `Text` because, once it enters `for` loop, there it will encounter a `return` statement..which will terminate the loop..

Comment: You can use the Row, Column OR Wrap with chipview, You can also use the Listview

Comment: should I turn ```Center(child: Text("check"))``` into Column?

Comment: see [Lay out multiple widgets vertically and horizontally](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout#lay-out-multiple-widgets-vertically-and-horizontally)

Comment: Pls do share a bit of code..where you are calling `cek()`..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once your `for` loop reaches the `return` statement it just returns `Center(child: Text("check"));` and cancels the loop.

If you want to return multiple widgets then you need to return a `List<Widget>`, if you want to return multiple widgets distributed vertically, than you need to return them on a `Column` (horizontally would be a `Row`).

It would be something like this:

```dart
Widget cek(){
  return Column(
    children: List.generate(3, (_) =>  Center(child: Text("check")));
  );
}
```

If you want to return a list of widgets to use later inside another widget, than it would be:

```dart
List<Widget> cek(){
  List.generate(3, (_) =>  Center(child: Text("check")));  
}
```

Comment: it works well.. thank you very much for your explanation and help :D

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this..

```
List<Widget> cek(){
  return List.generate(3, (i) =>  Center(child: Text("check")) );
}
```

Hope it solves your issue..

Comment: I am trying your code and I get an error that sys ```A value of type 'List<Center>' can't be returned from function 'cek' because it has a return type of 'Widget'.``` is there something that I should add?

Comment: you need to change the return type to `List<Widget>`

Comment: Yeah..as @shubham tanwar said..return type should be `List<Widget>`..my bad..and..fir some reason..it's not showing me the edit option for my answer..if possible, can someone edit that for me..!